# What are the differences between a physical and virtual RAM disk?

Tags: windows-7, memory, performance, ramdisk, benchmarking

I'm using [ImDisk](https://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/imdisk_toolkit_64_bit.html) to create a RAM disk for the purposes of creating an environment where I can run some performance benchmarks and ensure that all benchmarks run are consistent, by making sure any advantages from caching are applied to them all (by having the entirety of the data in memory).

[image]

However, ImDisk allows for the creation of two types of RAM disk - one created in virtual memory, and one created in physical memory. I've already learnt that a RAM disk created in physical memory is not persistent after a reboot, but what other differences are there between the two? Would a virtual RAM disk be sufficient for my use case, or do I need to use one that relies on physical RAM?

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Comment: Beware when using physical RAM only that you need to have more than enough RAM on the machine, or everything else will be constantly swapping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assigning physical memory will yield more consistent and faster results. Anything 'virtual' will be slower as per the experience shared at  http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-2047362/windows-virtual-memory-ram-disk.html . Virtual memory, [as Microsoft describes it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2160852/ram-virtual-memory-pagefile-and-memory-management-in-windows), will end up using hard disk space, which will definitely be slower.